# how to use a struct field with a double pointer variable (without a support variable)?

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, parameter-passing

I have this struct in c

```
struct node{
    int info;
    struct node* link;
};
```

this procedure:

```
void example(struct node** head){
    struct node* tmp;
    tmp=*head;
    tmp->info=0;
    *head=tmp;
}
```

and call the procedure in the main with

```
example(&head);
```

so to modify head->info I need a support variable,there is another way without a support variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
void example(struct node** head){
    (*head)->info=100;
}
```

It'll do the same as your `example` function. 
By dereferencing `struct node**` we get `struct node*`, then we can simply access it's member by using `->` arrow operator.

Comment: Happy structuring :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pointer to an object declared like

```
struct node *head; 
head = malloc( sizeof( struct head ) );
```

then you can just write

```
head->info = 10;
```

So as the object `info` is passed by reference to the function example there is no great sense to declare the parameter of the function as pointer to pointer

```
void example(struct node** head){
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can define the function like

```
void example(struct node *head){
    head->info=0;
}
```

You need to pass head by reference when head itself is changed in the function.

For example

```
void insert( struct node **head, int info )
{
    struct node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    tmp->link = *head;
    tmp->info = info

    *head = tmp;
  //^^^^^^^^^^^ 
}
```

If you need to change the data member info using pointer to pointer head then at first you need to dereference it to get pointer to the object info like and then apply the operator ->. For example

```
( *head )->info = 0;
```

In C if you want to change an object (that in particularly can be a pointer) in a function you have to pass it by reference that in C means passing an object through a pointer to it.